# Why is comma used while extending tuple by using asterisk in python?

Tags: python, tuples

In the below code if I don't use comma then only one 0 gets printed while if I use comma 0 gets printed five times, why? Is it something to do with the immutable trait of the tuple?

```
 food = (0,) * 5  # comma used
 print (*food)
```

Output: 0 0 0 0 0

```
 food = (0) * 5  # comma not used
 print (*food)
```

Output:0

Comment: How does the latter not give you a `TypeError`?

Comment: Because the latter is treated as a scalar expression.

Comment: `scalar expression` What is that? On the second example `food` is an integer, an you cannot unpack and integer, so you will get a TypeError

Comment: There is no TypeError for the second example, you can execute it yourself. Here food is a variable which is assigned to 0 as 0 inside the parenthesis is nothing but 0, 0 multiplied by 5 gives 0 which is very elementary. this multiplication part is a scalar expression.

Answer (score 2):

It's a syntax thing. What defines the tuple is not the parenthesis, but the presence of the comma:

- Parenthesis around a single scalar expression are used to define order of evaluation: `(1 + 2) * 3`
- A sequence of expressions separated by commas defines a tuple: `1, 2, 3`.

  - This sequence can then be parenthesized if it needs to be embedded in some other expression: `(1, 2, 3) * 5` is "the tuple (1,2,3) repeated five times".
- Specifically for a single-item tuple, the syntax requires a trailing comma to differentiate it from a parenthesized expression: `0,` is a tuple containing only the element 0; Usually you'd immediately want to parenthesize this expression if you wanted to embed it in a larger expression, e.g. `(0,) * 5` ("the tuple consisting of zero, multiplied five times"). Whereas `0` and `(0)` both mean "the integer zero" (parenthesized in the latter form).

```py
>>> type( (0, ) )
tuple

>>> type ( (0) )
int
```

So `(0) * 5` is "the integer 0 multiplied by 5", giving you 0. There's no tuple involved at any point because the syntax you used does not define a tuple.

Comment: @roganjosh You are 100% correct, my bad. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
>>> (0)
0
>>>
```

So `0 * 5` is `0`, while:

```
>>> (0,)
(0,)
>>>
```

Keeps it's type of a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

[Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) From documentation a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. **Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).** Ugly, but effective. For Example

```
>>> t=('hello')
>>> t
'hello'
>>> type(t)
<class 'str'>
>>> t1=('hello',)
>>> t1
('hello',)
>>> type(t1)
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to: [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - class **tuple**(*[iterable]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) (**emphasis** is mine):

> - Using a **trailing comma** for a singleton tuple: **a, or (a,)**

*food* definition (note that things would be the same without parentheses):

- In the 1<sup>st</sup> case, it's a *tuple* (as `(0,)` is a tuple)
- In the the 2<sup>nd</sup>  case, it's a plain *int* (***0 * 5***)

> ```py
> >>> v0 = (0,)
> >>> v1 = (0)
> >>>
> >>> v0, type(v0)
> ((0,), <class 'tuple'>)
> >>> v1, type(v1)
> (0, <class 'int'>)
> >>>
> >>> v0 * 5
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> >>> v1 * 5
> 0
> ```

**Are you absolutely sure that `print(*food)` works (as you claim it does) in the 2<sup>nd</sup> case**?